# Deploying an MDX Script into a Tabular Model

Tags: mdx, tabular

We have started migrating certain of our models to the Tabular technology (from multidimensional).  The Tabular models will be hosted in the Power BI (premium) service.  Most of the clients of our OLAP data are Excel pivot tables, or they are client processes that are executing MDX queries against the model.  These clients currently rely on legacy calculations that are written in MDX.  They also rely on certain features like default members within certain dimensions.

I was hopeful that we could retain our investments in MDX.  This might be possible if we designed tabular models that closely mirrored the legacy multidimensional cubes.  Here is a blog that seems to say tabular models would allow us to leverage existing MDX scripts:

https://prologika.com/dax-editor-adds-support-for-tabular-default-members/

> "Currently, Tabular doesn’t have UI for defining default members. However, you can define default members in the MdxScript section of the BIM file using MDX syntax just like you can do so in Multidimensional."

Unfortunately the blog was updated in mid-2019 with the following comment - **the new JSON schema is not extensible so this won't work.**

Based on that, it sounds as if things have changed to some degree.  We know, however, that tabular models are still capable of evaluating MDX queries, and a tabular connection/session is still able to define MDX calculated members.  So I'm hoping there is still a way to push MDX calculations back to the model, after it has been deployed... perhaps this might be possible using some sort of XMLA or TOM operation?

I realize that it is asking a lot.  And I realize that it is probably something Microsoft wouldn't want to advertise widely (or even support).  But given that MDX scripts were possible in the past, I'm hoping there is still some mechanism to use scripts.  It would allow us to preserve some large investments in MDX, while still migrating the storage model to Tabular.

Please let me know if anyone has tried to preserve their MDX investment, while migrating the underlying storage to use the Tabular structure.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, currently Default members arent supported; You can vote for this idea:  https://ideas.powerbi.com/ideas/idea/?ideaid=bae64f15-6dcb-ea11-bf21-281878bd39b4.

MDX statements are still valid. For example, if you connect to tabular model from Excel and when you query your data then excel sends MDX. Most of your query should work, but some of them may need a tweak.

You may try to mimic this logic by modifying MDX measure to DAX as described here.

https://www.tallan.com/blog/2017/01/24/analysis-services-tabular-dimensional-default-members/